# hamlでのprovide関数の書き方

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, haml

```
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Sample App</h1>
      <p>
        This is the home page for the
        <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
        sample application.
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

上記のhamlでの書き方を教えていただきたいです。
以下の変換サイトでは、正しく変換されずに困っています。
http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<% provide(:title, "Home") %>` が body の中のコンテンツとして認識されてしまうようです。`<% provide(:title, "Home") %>` を除いた形で変換したあと、Hamlの書式で先頭に追加すると良いでしょう。下記のような感じになるかと思います。

```
- provide(:title, "Home")
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title
      = yield(:title)
      | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App
  %body
    %h1 Sample App
    %p
      This is the home page for the
      %a{:href => "http://www.railstutorial.org/"} Ruby on Rails Tutorial
      sample application.
```